# Simple Solution to Make HTML More Modular

Tags: html

I am looking for a simple solution to make my html code more modular.  I want to be able to simply create some html files like `header`, `footer` and the like that I can use to create elements that will appear over all pages.

In other words, I would like to be able to create an html page that looks something like this:

```
--> import header.html

... unique page content goes here

--> import footer.html
```

With that said, I don't need a database or any reactive elements.  It's a simple html site.  So I am not looking to create a server or use a framework like React or Vue.JS.  All I want is a simple DRY html site.

Are there any solutions that can help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Browsers don't have any in-built way to include HTML in other HTML files. You'll either have to use client-side JS or a server-side framework to do so, and doing so on the server-side is going to be quicker (less hops back and forth).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like gulp.js, which gives you the option to combine multiple files into a single one.
You can read more about how to use gulp.js for your needs [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-modularize-html-using-template-engines-and-gulp-d1cb8af54138/)

For JavaScript, you can use "ejs" https://ejs.co/.

On the server-side, you can do this easily using a template engine.
As an example in a backend PHP framework like Laravel, you have this option by a template engine called Blade.

Answer (score 0):

There are many so-called "template engines" for this purpose. Perhaps the most natural one for HTML is SGML, since HTML is based on SGML. So I'm going to point you to [a tutorial for producing HTML using SGML](http://sgmljs.net/docs/producing-html-tutorial/producing-html-tutorial.html) I wrote for assembling HTML docs from header and footer pieces in exactly the way you describe. The SGML software used (http://sgmljs.net) works as a stand-alone command-line app, on the server-side (as a Node.js app), or in the browser.